# How to iterate scala wrappedArray? (Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I perform the following operations:

```
val tempDict = sqlContext.sql("select words.pName_token,collect_set(words.pID) as docids 
                               from words
                               group by words.pName_token").toDF()

val wordDocs = tempDict.filter(newDict("pName_token")===word)

val listDocs = wordDocs.map(t => t(1)).collect()

listDocs: Array

[Any] = Array(WrappedArray(123, 234, 205876618, 456))
```

My question is how do I iterate over this wrapped array or convert this into a list?

The options I get for the `listDocs` are `apply`,          `asInstanceOf`,   `clone`,          `isInstanceOf`,   `length`,         `toString`, and       `update`.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way to solve this.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

val data = Seq((Seq(1,2,3),Seq(4,5,6),Seq(7,8,9)))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)
val first = df.first

// use a pattern match to deferral the type
val mapped = first.getAs[WrappedArray[Int]](0)

// now we can use it like normal collection
mapped.mkString("\n")

// get rows where has array
val rows = df.collect.map {
    case Row(a: Seq[Any], b: Seq[Any], c: Seq[Any]) => 
        (a, b, c)
}
rows.mkString("\n")
```

Comment: Actually I did this and this seems to solve my case:
val arrDocs = listDocs(0)

val temp  = arrDocs.asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]]
The **temp** now basically gives me an iterator.

Comment: thanks @boY, I updated the answer. The previous one was a bit verbose.

Comment: I had issues with WrappedArray in my code and was able to replace it with Seq[Int].