# Scala: Listing files that match a regular expression within a directory

Tags: scala

I'm trying to list files within a directory that match a regular expression, e.g. ".csv$" this is very similar to [Scala & DataBricks: Getting a list of Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650777/scala-databricks-getting-a-list-of-files)

I've been running in circles for hours trying to figure out how Scala can list a directory of files and filter by regex.

```
import java.io.File

def getListOfFiles(dir: String):List[File] = {
    val d = new File(dir)
    if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
        d.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList
    } else {
        List[File]()
    }
}
val name : String = ".csv"

val files = getListOfFiles("/home/con/Scripts").map(_.path).filter(_.matches(name))
println(files)
```

gives the error

```
/home/con/Scripts/scala/find_files.scala:13: error: value path is not a member of java.io.File
val files = getListOfFiles("/home/con/Scripts").map(_.path).filter(_.matches(name))
```

I'm trying to figure out the regular Scala equivalent of `dbutils.fs.ls` which eludes me.

How can list files in a regular directory in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is reporting that **path** is not defined in `java.io.File` which it isn't.

If you want to match by name, why don't you get file names? Also, your regex is a bit off if you want to match based on file extension.

Fixing these two problems:

```
val name : String = ".+\\.csv"
val files = getListOfFiles("/path/to/files/location")
  .map(f => f.getName)
  .filter(_.matches(name))
```

will output *.csv* files in the */path/to/files/location* folder.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove `getCanonicalFile` which was unncessary in this case.